# In the Following Code Shows in the Statement "return view == Object;"

Tags: android-viewpager, picasso

Sir
I am new to android programming. I tried to use ViewPager to display multiple side scrolling images using Picasso.

The Code given is copied from Youtube Video to use View Pager. But in the following function the statement return view == Object; Object shows error as undefined symbol.

```
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object o) {
        return view == Object;
    }
```

The entire code like Mainactivity Java, ViewAdpater Class and the XMl are given below

ViewPagerAdapter class

```
package com.example.imageapp;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private String[] imageUrls;
    ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] imageUrls){
        this.context=context;
        this.imageUrls=imageUrls;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object o) {
        return view == Object;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        Picasso. get()
                .load(imageUrls[position])
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(imageView);
        container.addView(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
       container.removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

Main Activity.java

```
package com.example.imageapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.squareup.picasso.Callback;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import static android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String[] imageUrls = new String[]{
        "http://www.geocities.ws/mariyanaatham/2019/may/1.png",
        "http://www.geocities.ws/mariyanaatham/2019/may/2.png"
};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter= new ViewPagerAdapter(this,imageUrls);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        /*String MY_URL_STRING ="http://www.geocities.ws/mariyanaatham/2019/may/1.png";
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Picasso.get()
                .load(MY_URL_STRING)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.mary)
                .into(iv);*/
    }


}
```

Activity_Main XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My intention is to show multiple side scrollable images loaded from URL**strong text**

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion the code was copied incorrectly, cause it doesn't make sense. It shouldn't even compile. You have a link to the video?

Comment: sir, 
Sorry for troubling you, I have solved it as:
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object o) {
        return view == Object;
changing the line
return view == Object to 
return view ==o;
Thanks four your reply;